# Does `adb shell top` show the average cpu usage over the update time?

Tags: android, adb

When calling `adb shell top` with Android to measure cpu usage, is the cpu usage percentage that is shown the average over the update time, or a snapshot of the usage over a shorter time, specifically, if I increase the update time using `-d`, will it give me the average cpu use over that whole period?

Comment: a quick glance at https://android.googlesource.com/platform/system/core/+/lollipop-release/toolbox/top.c would have taken less time than typing the question

Answer (score 0):

I compared the top -d to the CPU usage reported by the default system monitor.I tried both "top -d 1" and "top -d 10." Just to cover a short as well as large period. 
In both the cases top -d was not giving the instantaneous CPU usage. So I'm guessing the it is the **average CPU usage over that period.**

PS:There were significant difference in both the cases.Also I used top -d in my linux system. I am assuming that the working of both adb top and linux top will the same as android is based on linux.

Comment: You happen to be right this time. but guessing and assumptions belong to the comment section. The answers are for proven facts